# Limit of f(x). What does it tell about Limit of f(x)^n?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$. Is it telling us something about $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^n$?

Comment: Are you talking about the limit as $n\to\infty$? Or something like $x\to x_0$?

Comment: Yes. When n is converging to infinity

Comment: Is $L$ a real number?

Comment: Yes, L is a real number

Comment: Are you saying that $f(x)$ is a constant function, or that a certain limit of $f(x)$ is $L$?

Comment: I have edited the question to what I feel the OP is trying to ask.

Comment: Joe made it clear now (look at the edit of my question please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\phi(x) = x^n$ is continuous, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$, hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(f(x)) = \phi(\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)) = \phi(L) = L^n$.

Answer (score 1):

[This answers  a different question. Namely, the one I thought the OP was asking before the post was edited.]

If $\lvert L\rvert$>1 this goes to $\infty$. If $\lvert L\rvert$<1 this goes to $0$. If $L=1$ this goes to $1$. If $L=-1$ this sequence does not converge.

In any case, this has nothing to do with $L$ being equal to the value of some function at some point.

Comment: Indeed. I have answered a different question. Namely, the one I thought the OP was asking before it was edited.